# how to use similarity algorithm for keys of hadoop map resuce job

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, cascading

I need to implement the following problem: 
I'm getting the data of type

```
public class Data{   
  private String key;
  private String valueData;
}
```

I need to write a map reduce job to get all **unique** keys, with one (random) valueData for each of them.
Sound very simple for hadoop, and Yep, I know how to implement this.

But the real problem is that, I need also to reduce all "**similar**" keys.
And the output should be one of the similar **key** with one of the **dataValue**

What is the best way (and how) to implemet this in hadoop? I would also like to have a flexebility to change the similarity algorithm.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I just want to clarify even more basic question. When I'm using Map/Reduce the Reduce get's all the same keys with list of values. How can I "update" the default map reduce key comparator, so only one of similar keys will come to the Reduce function? I'm looking for simple java Map/Reduce code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the `MinHashing` technique, it is widely used with MapReduce for this task.

The similarity metric is bound to `Jaccard`, not sure if there are other approaches. However once you computed near keys you can use another metric to measure the similarity between them, because minhashing has drastically reduced your searchspace.

You can read more on wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MinHash

Mahout has a `MinHash` clustering algorithm, you can have a look there. It is pretty easy to understand and features several hashing algorithms.

Comment: thank, it's nice, I'll look at mahout usage. If I'm writing my composite key and override methods -equals- and -compareTo- methods,  but not override -hashCode- will my code work correctlly?

Comment: You need to vectorize your keys, I assume your key is text, so you can use shingling (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W-shingling) to make the search more fuzzy. Mahout takes care of vectorizing your text keys and then can cluster up on them.

Answer (score 0):

You essentially need to come up with a function, `f`, such that, as nearly as possible:

```
f(A) = f(B) if and only if A and B are "similar"
```

Now exactly how strictly you are able to conform to this is entirely dependent on what exactly the domain of these values is, and what your similarity metric is, but this is the goal.

As an example, if the keys were real numbers, then I might choose `f(x) = round(x)`. For values of x that are very close, it is likely that `f(x)` will be the same, but possible that it's different, e.g., 2.45 and 2.55. But maybe you can allow this "good enough"-ness.

Then, you can just make the key to your reduce step the output of this function.

I'll also add that there are lots of other sophisticated techniques for specific similarity metrics and specific clustering methods - maybe I could point you to one of those if you gave a little more detail on what types of metrics you're hoping to use, or what exactly the "similar" keys are.